# What do the stars mean in Zombie Gunship Survival?

Tags: zombie-gunship-survival

It seems like there is no difference in stats.

Three stars:
[image]

Two stars:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience has been that the stars represent a cap on the level.  So a 1-star weapon could go up to lvl 10, but after that it needs to be Fused to become 2-star, and continue leveling.

I haven't tried leveling to 20 yet, but I suspect 2-star weapons will cap at level 20.

Comment: Please note that levelling a two star weapon from level 1 to level 2 is far more expensive than levelling a one star weapon from level 1 to level 2. Three star weapons are even worse and I expect that this continues with every further star.

Answer (score 0):

I think every time you go up 10 levels it gains a star. If you keep boosting it will keep going up. [image]

Answer (score -1):

I found out it's better having a boosted 1 star weapon than a 3 star non boosted. Boosting a 3 star weapon is so expensive but the damage seems off, it looks like the leveling and weapon damage is broken in this game.  Having a weapon with one star is actually better.  [image]

Comment: That looks like a 2-star, not a 1-star.